# Where can I enable "get-task-allow" in xcode 4.5 for iCloud debugging (with entitlements file)?

Tags: xcode, debugging, icloud, provisioning

I'm an expert in iOS development since years. And long long time ago I've had the problem with debugging while using entitlement files. Setting "get-task-allow" to YES in the entitlement file fixed the problem.

Now I did an upgrade to Xcode 4.5 and "get-task-allow" is not working anymore! Has anyone a clue where apple moved this feature to? I can still use the ad hoc profile or disable and delete the entitlement to run the code. But I need the debugger.

Astonishingly using the Team-Provisioning-Profile is working. I need to access KV-Store-Values with another "team identifier id". Actually I am completely unable to debug iCloud.

Does anyone has any idea? I'm lost here.

Thanks in advance

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

'get-task-allow' seems not to be needed anymore. I manually created new certificates and removed the team identifier ID from my certificate list. Then it worked.